# Camera is not working in android ionic react app

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have this code it is working in PC browser but in android it will not open the camera. The code is written in ionic framework using React components. The main component which opens camera is as below:

```
import React, { useRef, useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import './index.scss';

const CAPTURE_OPTIONS = {
  audio: true,
  video: { facingMode: "user" }
};

const Camera: React.FC = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const [mediaStream, setMediaStream] = useState<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function enableStream() {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(CAPTURE_OPTIONS);
        setMediaStream(stream);
      } catch (err) {
        // Removed for brevity
      }
    }

    if (!mediaStream) {
      enableStream();
    } else {
      return function cleanup() {
        mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track: any) => {
          track.stop();
        });
      }
    }
  }, [mediaStream, CAPTURE_OPTIONS]);

  if (mediaStream && videoRef.current && !videoRef.current.srcObject) {
    videoRef.current.srcObject = mediaStream;
  }

  const handleCanPlay = () => {
    videoRef.current.play();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={videoRef} onCanPlay={handleCanPlay} autoPlay playsInline loop muted className={"camera"} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Camera;
```

Does anyone knows that what is the problem  I have this problem for running the code on android capacitor and when I run `ionic capacitor run android --livereload --external` I cant get sth like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using webrtc and 
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()
you need to make sure that you are using the adapter.js file.

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/webrtc-adapter,
or copy the file from - https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/tree/master/release.
If you want it globally put it in your public folder of your ionic project.